# malformed config.xml in PhoneGapBuild

Tags: xml

Can anybody please tell me why this xml file will not allow my app to build. It is within a zip folder at the same level as my index.html file. The app builds fine without it but wont with this config file added. I originally had additional features, icons and splash screens but I could not get it to build, I have now  stripped it down and it still wont build, can anybody help please?

Here is the code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.rochdaleflorist"
    version = "1.0.0">
    <name>Flower Corner</name>
    <description>
    An application to order flowers
    </description>
    <author href = "http://www.rochdaleflorist.com"    email="barry.gilligan@btinternet.com">
    Barry Gilligan
    </author>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
    </widget>
```

Comment: You should include the full text of the build error.

Comment: Thank you, the error message is "malformed config.xml"